# Android (ADB) debug with Arduino USB host

Tags: android, arduino, adb, adk

I have tested Arduino ADK and Android communication over USB, but I can not debug an Android application, because USB is connected to the Arduino.

Is there a workaround solution?

I tried to connect [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) over wireless, but USB host with Arduino doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Wireless ADB is the only way to debug while the USB port is in use. With ADB enabled and connected via USB:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect <Device IP>:5555
```

to go back to using USB ADB:

```
adb usb
```